# Does Integrated Windows Authentication work in Firefox?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, windows-authentication, adfs

If my ASP.NET app is set up for ADFS using Windows Integrated Authentication, I know this will work in IE, but will it work in Firefox?

I've seen some things on the web that indicate that there are problems, and you need to put a workaround in each client browser - http://codebetter.com/blogs/eric.wise/archive/2006/11/16/Note-to-self_3A00_-Firefox-Windows-Authentication.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a workaround. Firefox will not send your Windows Integrated Credentials to a website by default.  You have to tell it to "trust" the website.

You could display those instructions on a page you direct unauthenticated users to.

Comment: Thanks, in retrospect "workaround" wasn't the right terminology - I just meant that each user would have to make changes to their browser.